# How to bind data to a mat form field in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, templates

I have an http request that pulls that data and I am populating this data on the UI. Now when the user clicks edit a form will show . How do we assign and show the value on the fields when the edit button was clicked ? cause I wanna use that data to submit. The email , firstname etc should display on the field.

When I click edit the value of the form field should be the value from the getuserdetails like firstname , lastname etc like the sample below {{this.data.emailAddress}} but instead I want it to be value of the input field

#init

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      this.userId = params.id;
      this.getUserGeneralDetails();
    });
  }
```

#constructor

```
 constructor(
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private _notificationService: NotificationService,
    private _userProfileService: UserProfileService,
    private _router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.generalForm.disable();
    this.securityForm.disable();
  }
```

I only wanna show the data on the formfield when Edit is clicked.

```
 generalForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl(),
    fname: new FormControl(),
    lname: new FormControl(),
    phone: new FormControl(),
    companyName: new FormControl(),
    title: new FormControl(),
  });
```

Just new to angular guys badly wanted to know techniques and ideas. Thank you.

[image]

---

[image]
#template

```
 <div class="card" #generalCard>
            <span class="anchor" id="general"></span>
            <div class="card-header">
                <mat-icon class="card-icon">group</mat-icon>
                <div class="title">GENERAL</div>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <button mat-button *ngIf="generalForm.disabled" (click)="generalForm.enable()">
                    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon> Edit
                </button>
                <button mat-button *ngIf="generalForm.enabled" (click)="generalForm.disable()">
                    Cancel
                </button>
                <button mat-stroked-button *ngIf="generalForm.enabled" (click)="saveGeneralFormChanges()">
                    Save Changes
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content" *ngIf="generalForm.disabled" >
                <div class="line-item">
                    <div class="title">EMAIL</div>
                    <div class="detail">{{this.data.emailAddress}}</div>
                    <mat-icon class="active" style="color:#00B0DB;">check_circle</mat-icon>
                </div>

                <div class="line-item">
                    <div class="title">EMAIL</div>
                    <div class="detail">{{this.data.emailAddress}}</div>
                    <mat-icon>check_circle_outline</mat-icon>
                    <button mat-button class="detail active">Resend welcome email</button>
                </div>

                <div class="line-item">
                    <div class="title">FIRST NAME</div>
                    <div class="detail">{{this.data.firstName}}</div>
                </div>

                <div class="line-item">
                    <div class="title">LAST NAME</div>
                    <div class="detail">{{this.data.lastName}}</div>
                </div>

                <div class="line-item">
                    <div class="title">PHONE NUMBER</div>
                    <div class="detail">+1 {{this.data.phoneNumber}}</div>
                </div>

                <div class="line-item">
                    <div class="title">COMPANY NAME</div>
                    <div class="detail">{{this.data.companyName || 'None'}}</div>
                </div>

                <div class="line-item">
                    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
                    <div class="detail">{{this.data.title || 'None'}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

#GetUserData

```
getUserGeneralDetails() {
    this.isInProgress = true;
    this._userProfileService
      .getUserGeneralDetails(this.userId)
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isInProgress = false)))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          if (res.isSuccess) {
            this.data = res.data;
          }
        },
        error: (err) => this._notificationService.showError(err),
        complete: noop,
      });
  }
```

#field code

```
<div class="card-content" *ngIf="generalForm.enabled">
                <form [formGroup]="generalForm" class="generalForm">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="email">
                        <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
                        <input matInput formControlName="email" />
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <button mat-raised-button class="validateEmail">Validate email</button>
                    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="fname">
                        <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
                        <input matInput formControlName="fname" />
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="lname">
                        <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
                        <input matInput formControlName="lname" />
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="phone">
                        <mat-label>Phone Number</mat-label>
                        <input matInput formControlName="phone" />
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="companyName">
                        <mat-label>Company Name</mat-label>
                        <input matInput formControlName="companyName" />
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="title">
                        <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
                        <input matInput formControlName="title" />
                    </mat-form-field>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: In this case (a data entry form) I would use an Angular reactive form for the task. See https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: I have added a form control above Sir

Comment: You must follow the reactive forms documentation, it's not appropriate for me to just copy it into an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code looks like good and as per ur question you are facing issue in filling data into form controls. That can be done as follow:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

fillUpData() {
     this.generalForm = this.fb.group({
         email: [this.data.email, [Validators.required]],
         fname: [this.data.fname, [Validators.required]],
         lname: [this.data.lname, [Validators.required]],
         phone: this.data.phone,
         companyName: this.data.companyName,
         title: this.data.title
    });
}
```

You need to call this method once you have data. So after your API call.

```
getUserGeneralDetails() {
    this.isInProgress = true;
    this._userProfileService
      .getUserGeneralDetails(this.userId)
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isInProgress = false)))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          if (res.isSuccess) {
            this.data = res.data;   // After this call function.
            this.fillUpData();
          }
        },
        error: (err) => this._notificationService.showError(err),
        complete: noop,
      });
  }
```

After doing this if you get an error related to the form group then add condition like *ngIf="generalForm" in your HTML code... That means if form exist then render its formControl...

Comment: Sir I only want to show the matform field and the forms if the Edit button is clicked only but right now it is showing everytime the page loads , I have updated my code above. Thanks

Comment: <button mat-button *ngIf="generalForm.disabled" (click)="generalForm.enable()">
                    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon> Edit
                </button>

Comment: You can create one local variable to detect if its editMode. On click of edit button just set the editMode = true otherwise set false when you display only values.